Rad Studio 12 returns incorrect screen sizes
I have started moving a C++ FireMonkey project from RAD Studio 10.3 to the latest 12.1.
However, Screen->Displays doesn't return the correct screen size and location anymore. Code which runs fine under 10.3 doesn't work under 12.1.
My laptop has two external monitors, making 3 screens total.
Using the Display Settings control panel, I can see that screen 1 is 3840 x 2400, Screen 2 and 3 are 1920 x 1080.  My screens are ordered 3, 2, 1. With Left for Screen 3 being 0, Left for Screen 2 is 1920 and Left for Screen 3 is 3840.
I am using the screen positions to place a form to fill the entire screen, so having correct size and location is very important.
When I run this code under 12.1:
Screen->UpdateDisplayInformation();
for (int i = 0; i < Screen->DisplayCount; i++)
{
  MainForm->LogMsg("Screen : " + IntToStr (i + 1) + "," +
                                 IntToStr((int)Screen->Displays[i].Bounds.Width()) + "," +
                                 IntToStr((int)Screen->Displays[i].Bounds.Height()));
}

I get:
Screen : 1,1536,960
Screen : 2,1920,1080
Screen : 3,1920,1080

If I get the workarea instead, I get:
Screen : 1,1536,960
Screen : 2,1920,1032
Screen : 3,1920,1080

Screens 2 and 3 are correct, but screen 1 is incorrect, as is the screen location.
If I try to position a form to fill screen 1, it appears instead in screen 3's location.
If I switch back to build under 10.3, all works fine, sizes and positions are correct.
Hopefully someone can tell me why this no longer works.

have you tried to run https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Multiple_Display_Support ?

@IłyaBursov how is that any different than what the OP showed? They are already using the properties described in that page.

@RemyLebeau not really, there are more in rad's example, like workarea

@IłyaBursov which the OP said they also tried.

@BarryAndrews what plattform are you running your code on? If Windows, what is the DPI awareness of your app set to? on Windows, Screen->Displays[] scales the reported Bounds and Workarea values based on GetDpiForMonitor(), which returns different values based on the calling process's DPI awareness. But FMX also adjusts the Bounds and Workarea based on some internal TDpPxConverter class that I have no idea what it's trying to do.

Running on Windows 11, 64 bit, DPI awareness is set to None.

I tried changing DPI awareness to "per Monitor", it came up with the same size.  Interestingly, Screen 1 location appears to be centered around where the application main form is displayed, not where the actual screen is.  Is there a different method I can use just to get location and size of each monitor in pixels so I can position my forms?  I don't want to trust Firemonkey to make the choice.

I worked out the issue. I was setting the form position, then using Form->Show() to display the form, this worked on C++ Builder 10.3, on C++ Builder 12.1 I need to show the form first, then set the position.  This works reliably, showing last was making the form take on form->Position setting.

Also, Monitor 1 has a scale of 2.5 which explains the size difference from what I expected. Making the app DPI aware per monitor now correctly fills the scaled screen. Thanks for all the suggestions, really helped me out.

The issue was that I was setting the form position, then using Form->Show() to display the form, this worked on C++ Builder 10.3 (I am not sure it should have). On C++ Builder 12.1, I need to show the form first, then set the position to the monitor position and size. If I show as the last action the form is re positioned to its design time "Position" parameter.
This now works reliably.
The screen size being different was because monitor 1 has a scale of 2.5, when multiplied by this scale the size is as per the monitor.
